# Git: Merging repositories with related histories into one

Tags: git, merge, repository

Let's say I have two repositories where the first repo's history ends where the second one's begins. Like this:

```
A -- B   C -- D
```

How do I merge them so that I have this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`git filter-branch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) has an example on how to do this:

> To set a commit (which typically is at the tip of another history) to be the parent of the current initial commit, in order to paste the other history behind the current history:
>
> ```
> git filter-branch --parent-filter 'sed "s/^\$/-p <graft-id>/"' HEAD
> ```

To create a virtual parent instead of rewriting the entire history, consider using [`git replace --graft`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace)

Comment: Could you give me an example of how exactly to use this with two repositories?

Comment: Perhaps something like: from the D branch, `get fetch repo-with-B B` then `ref=$(get rev-parse B) && git filter-branch --parent-filter 'sed "s/^\$/-p '$ref'/"' HEAD`